# Split a variable in js or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, split

Hi I have some vars like this:

```
var a = Base-Shirt_Stripe.jpg
var b = Closed-Flatknit-Collar_Stripe.png
```

How do i create two new vars like:

```
var c = Base-Shirt
var d = Stripe
```

or

```
var e = Closed-Flatknit-Collar
var f = Stripe
```

basically split at the `_` remove the `_` and remove the extension.

Comment: [Googled your exact question :)](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=Split+a+variable+in+js+or+jquery&oq=Split+a+variable+in+js+or+jquery&gs_l=hp.3..33i29i30l3.2964.2964.0.4491.1.1.0.0.0.0.112.112.0j1.1.0...0.0...1c.2.8.psy-ab.T6a1KvKwTC0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44770516,d.aWM&fp=f18f27e046486f57&biw=1300&bih=869)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//for example, we take a
var a = 'Base-Shirt_Stripe.jpg';

//then we take the part of a before the dot
//and split between `_`
//split returns an array
var split = a.substring(0,a.indexOf('.'))
             .split('_');

//split is an array, so we use indices to indicate which
console.log(split[0]); //Base-Shirt
console.log(split[1]); //Stripe
```

[Sample here](http://jsfiddle.net/y9YYW/). You can do the same for your `b`

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I was hoping to get!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make them strings to start with, then use [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to split the string into an array of the different parts.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KJqqj/1/)

```
var a = "Base-Shirt_Stripe.jpg"
var b = "Closed-Flatknit-Collar_Stripe.png"

var aSplit = a.substr(0, a.lastIndexOf('.')).split('_');

var c = aSplit[0];
var d = aSplit[1];

var bSplit = b.substr(0, b.lastIndexOf('.')).split('_');

e = bSplit[0];
f = bSplit[1];
```

You could also take the removal of the extension out into its own function using [`String.lastIndexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) and [`String.substr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr).

```
function removeExtension(file) {
    return file.substr(0, file.lastIndexOf('.'));
}
```

Comment: `removeExtension` will not work for filename like `"Dress.Base-Shirt_Strip.jpg"` . I suggest `"Dress.Base-Shirt_Strip.jpg".split('.').slice(0, -1 ).join('')`

Comment: Updated with a more robust solution.

Answer (score 0):

may be you could do like

```
var a = "Base-Shirt_Stripe.jpg"
var k = a.replace(/(\.\w*)$/g, "").split("_");

alert(k[0]);
alert(k[1]);
```

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VtdpV/1/)

Answer (score -1):

```
//Javascript Split can divide it into parts. Javascript Split return type is array.'

 //e g.

var a = Base-Shirt_Stripe.jpg
var parts = a.split('_');

 console.log(parts[0]);
    //output
    " Base-Shirt "

 //parts[0] contain base-shirt and    parts[1]   contain Stripe.jpg.
```